Angular Validators.pattern() not working with type="number", works with type="text"
I've got the following input element for entering (part of) a phone number in an Angular 18 app with the associated Validators.pattern(/^[1-9]\d{5,}/):
  ...
  form = this.formBuilder.group({
    someSection: this.formBuilder.group({
      phone: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^[1-9]\d{5,}/)]],
  ...

...
<input type="text" formControlName="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
...

I require that

only digits are allowed
the first digit must be in the range from 1-9 inclusive
there are at least six digits in total

The above code and pattern works, but having type="text" for the input allows entering characters. When I change it to type="number" I can't enter characters as expected, but then my pattern validation fails - if I enter six or more digits with a leading zero, the control validates without error.
Is there a way to make this work by combining type="number" and the needed validation pattern? Or will I have to manually prevent entering of non-numeric input?

The solution to allow only numbers, is to listen for keypress event and ensure that number keyCodes alone return true, else return false.
You should prefer type="string" since your inputs accept zero at the beginning, which type="number" does not consider and omits it.
SO Answer - Prevent user from typing non-number input
import { Component, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { JsonPipe } from '@angular/common';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [JsonPipe, ReactiveFormsModule],
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="form">
      <input type="string" formControlName="phone" placeholder="Phone" (keypress)="IsNumeric($event)"/>
    </form>

    {{form.controls.phone.errors | json}}
  `,
})
export class App {
  formBuilder = inject(FormBuilder);
  form = this.formBuilder.group({
    phone: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^[1-9]\d{5,}/)]],
  });
  specialKeys: Array<any> = [];

  IsNumeric(e: any) {
    const keyCode = e.keyCode == 0 ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
    return (keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) ||
    (this.specialKeys.indexOf(e.keyCode) != -1 && e.charCode != e.keyCode);;
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

Thank you, confirmed my assumption. I did choose telas type in the end though.
